# To prove that a theta series of a quadratic form is a modular form

Tags: fourier-series, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $q$ be an odd prime, and $Q$ be the quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^4$ defined as
$$Q(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_0^2+4q^2(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)$$
My aim is to prove that the theta function series
$$\Theta_Q(z) = \sum \limits_{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{Z}^4} e^{2 \pi i Q(\vec{x}) z}$$
is a (weakly) modular form of weight $2$ and level $16q^2$.

Now suppose we want to show that a given function $f:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a (weakly) modular form of weight $k$ for the modular group $\Gamma$, we can exploit the fact that $\Gamma$ is generated by the functions
$$z \mapsto z+1$$
$$z \mapsto -1/z$$
and so it is enough to show that
$$f(z)=f(z+1)$$
$$f(-1/z)=z^kf(z)$$

But what do we do when the level is not $1$? Do we know of any generators for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma(16q^2)$?

It is easy to see, simply by definition, that
$$\Theta_Q(z+1)=\Theta_Q(z)$$
I then tried using the Poisson summation formula on the function 
$$e^{- \pi \vec{v}.\vec{v}}$$
with the lattice $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ comprising vectors of the form $(v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3)^T$ where $v_0/\sqrt{2},v_1/2\sqrt{2}q,v_2/2\sqrt{2}q,v_3/2\sqrt{2}q \in \mathbb{Z}$ but that is not of much help since I am not even sure what to aim for. What I have is
$$\Theta_{Q^*}\left( -\frac{1}{z} \right) = - 32q^3 z^2  \Theta_{Q}(z)$$
where $Q^*$ is a "dual" form defined as
$$Q^{*}(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_0^2+\frac{1}{4q^2}(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)$$

By the way, I am a computer science student trying to understand the Ramanujan graph construction by Lubotsky et al, so I am only now scratching the surface of modular forms. I tried looking up references, but they get in too deep and I lose direction.

Comment: You can still use poisson summation to obtain a transformation formula for $z \mapsto -1/z$. Of course, it is not transforming like a modular form in this case, but you obtain a general formula for arbitrary matrices in $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Afterwards you use gauss sums to obtain the transformation as a modular form for matrices in a congruence subgroup. For details you could look up the general proof in most books about modular forms. A few examples:
Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms (H. Iwaniec),
Lattices and Codes (W. Ebeling),
Modular Forms (T. Miyake)

Comment: I did obtain a transformation formula for $z \mapsto -1/z$ using the Poisson summation. Just not sure what to do after that or how to connct that with congruence subgroups. "Afterwards you use gauss sums to obtain the transformation as a modular form for matrices in a congruence subgroup"- this is precisely what my question is about.
Will try looking up your references, though as I mentioned, most references go too much into rigor and detail that I lose track of my modest aims. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't think you can find a proof just for a specific theta function. The proof is rather long to be stated here and it is mostly technical calculation.